# Retrieve the bitmap to its original height and width - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Sample Code:

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas1">
      <!-- Overlayed Images Will Go Here -->
      <Image Name="Image1" Height="575" Source="..."/>
      <Image Name="Image2" Height="100" Source="..."/>
</Canvas>
```

The actual height of the IMAGE1 is "1130". But while I am showing onto the screen, the height of the IMAGE1 is "575" as shown above. Now, I want to save this back to hard disk as a JPEG file. Because, now there are two images which are overlayed images in the Canvas. Here is the sample code I do have to do that:

```
public static void CreateAndSaveBitmap(Image Image1, Canvas canvas, string filename)
{
      try
      {
            double Height = Image1.Height;  // Here is one change
            double Width = Image1.Width;  // Here is another change

            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Width, (int)Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            canvas.Measure(new Size((int)Width, (int)Height));
            canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size((int)Width, (int)Height)));

            renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

            using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
            {
                  encoder.Save(file);
            }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
}
```

I can able to save the image, but the problem is, it is not having its original height of "1130" - which is its original height. It has the height of "575" - which is shown on UI. And the rest of the image is filled with black in color. If you can provide me piece of sample code to fix this, that will be great !

Comment: Create a new Canvas and new Image controls in code, set their Source properties, add them to the Canvas, call Measure and Arrange, and finally Render.

Comment: The code you wrote essentially takes a screen shot.  The Canvas is not 8.5 by 11, so any part of that 8.5x11 area that is not covered by the Canvas will be black.

Comment: Moby Disk - I made the changes to the above program. Now, I am not getting the Black. But the created image is having height "575". I want to stretch it to its original height and width of IMAGE1. Any help ?

Comment: Clemens - Your method is working very well. Now, I got what I need.

Comment: Since @Clemens solution worked, you can post that an answer to your own question.  That helps other people who come here, and if someone upvotes your answer then you get reputation.